# Access ubuntu localhost from node server inside docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, docker, localhost

I have a node server running inside a docker container and the docker container is running in ubuntu 16.04. I have service running on the ubuntu localhost. 
I am trying to access that localhost from the node server but keeps getting ECONNREFUSED. Is there any fix to this problem?

Comment: share your Dockerfile

Comment: FROM node:carbon
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 11777
CMD ["npm","run","build"]
CMD ["npm","start"]

Comment: Are you running on Linux, Windows, or Mac?

Comment: my docker and django service is running on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Maybe expose the node server port on a different port.

```
docker run -d -p <host_port>:<container_exposed_port> -t <image_name>
```

And access to the exposed port.

Comment: i am not trying to access my node server. i am trying to access a django service outside the docker container.
i run the command docker run -p 11777:11777 and the django service runs on 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Try `docker run -p 8000:8000`, and access it on localhost:8000

Comment: my django service is not dockerized